# Copy cells in excel using C#

Tags: c#, excel, interop, copy

How to copy to specific row in target sheet?

I need to copy A1 to J10 from a sheet in one excel to location starting from A15 in second excel sheet. How can I achieve this in c#? In the below Copy method there seems to be no option to specify the location in target excel sheet.

```
ObjWorkSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)ObjWorkBookTemp.Sheets[1];
ObjWorkSheet.Copy(Type.Missing, ObjWorkBookGeneral.Sheets[1]);
```

Comment: Depending on how much work you're doing with Excel files, I'd recommend looking into a third party application such as http://www.spreadsheetgear.com

Answer (score 9):

I think you are using the wrong method here... you want to use a Paste method not a copy method.

Try the Range.PasteSpecial method... should do the trick for you.

Something like this...

```
Excel.Range sourceRange = firstWorksheet.get_Range("A1", "J10");
Excel.Range destinationRange = secondWorksheet.get_Range("A15", "J25");

sourceRange.Copy(Type.Missing);
destinationRange.PasteSpecial(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPasteType.xlPasteFormulas, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPasteSpecialOperation.xlPasteSpecialOperationNone, false, false);
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Also how can I set row height of a range of rows in the destination excel. Looks like height property is read only.

Comment: @Anand - use the RowHeight property of the range

Comment: I'm trying to get this working and while it copies formatting fine, it does not copy formulas. I am copying between different workbooks in distinct Excel Application objects.